# Changing select content according to another select value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have select, I want user to choose one of its option .according to the selected option the other select show some options.
the second select retrieve its value from db via query . the some value should be a selected value from the first select .can any body help?

```
<select name="select2">
            <option value="--">--------</option>
            <?php
                $stmt = "SELECT * FROM XXX where f=somevalue";      
                $data = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $stmt);
                if ($data == false){}
                elseif (sqlsrv_fetch_array($data) == 0){}
                else {$data = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $stmt);
                      while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"><?php echo $row["name"]?></option>
            <?php }}?>
          </select>
```

Comment: I cant figure out where's the problem. If you want to change options in second select according to selected option in first select then add event handler on first select that must trigger on 'change' and write code to add relevant options in second select.

Comment: function val() {
    d = document.getElementById("entity").value;}

 <select name="entity" id="entity" onChange="val()">
                      <option value="--">.........

I need the selected value to make query to fill the other drop downlist

Comment: you need to use ajax

Comment: is there any way in java script ??? or php???

Comment: So checklist is event handler is ready and it will trigger on change. You had function to get a call on event. Now you write a logic to construct an array which options should be shown to user in second select. Then pass that array to function. I'm adding function source to answer for easy to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Once you got what to show on second select, create an array and pass it to this function

```js
function addToSelect(optionsToAdd) {
                sNum = 0
                for(option of optionsToAdd) {
                    sNum += 1
                    indivOption = document.createElement("option")
                    indivOption.innerText = option
                    indivOption.setAttribute("value", sNum)
                    document.getElementsByClassName("select-class")[0].appendChild(indivOption)
                }
 }
addToSelect(["choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3", "choice 4"])
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <select class="select-class">
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```